# ClassNotFound Exception in cljtime

Tags: clojure, classnotfound

I have this piece of code in my proj

```
(use 'clj-time.format)
```

but it seems it keeps on giving me an exception like this

```
ClassNotFoundException org.joda.time.ReadablePartial java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run
```

I am sure that i have added it to the class path and the API was downloaded from github

Comment: Are you using Leiningen ?

Comment: @Blacksad i am using Clooj

Comment: It is very likely that you placed only `clj-time` jar on your classpath, but not `joda-time`, on which `clj-time` depends. `ReadablePartial` class, which cannot be found, belongs to `joda-time` library. If you must use manual library management, download `joda-time`, e.g. from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/ and put it onto your classpath.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I have tried your suggestion but it doesnt seem to work also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clooj is a nice clojure IDE though it is not a project management tool like leiningen. The clooj project page [recommends using Leiningen to manage your dependencies](https://github.com/arthuredelstein/clooj).

```
 Inside the src directory is the source code hierarchy, composed of 
directories and .clj files. Note this directory structure is completely 
compatible with the lein build tool for clojure. We recommend the 
use of lein in alongside the clooj editor.
```

to get this working, It may help if you:

- [download leiningen](http://leiningen.org/)
- run lein new peoject-time
- add `[clj-time "0.5.1"]` to the :dependencies section
- run `lein deps` from the terminal
- restart clooj